# Cant update to Angular 8 since the command is not found

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, command-line-interface, ionic4

I want to upgrade my ionic application. First I tried to do it with

> ng update

But all thing with `ng` do not work since it says

> bash: ng: command not found

Then I tried

> npm update

what actually did something but all my dependencies are still `7.x.x.` So the last thing I tried was to address just one dependency like

> npm install @angular/core@latest

or

> npm install  @angular/cli@latest

this actually worked, so these both are `8.x.x`. but I want all things to update once. I have no idea why the other updated are not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install `@angular/cli` globally in order to access the `ng` command.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Notice the `-g` here, it stands for `global`

If this is already installed, you might want to check your `$PATH` to make sure it contains the location the globally installed libraries. If not, you need to add it to your `$PATH` environement variable.

On Windows, the npm usually install it's global package in

```
%APPDATA%\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

As for Unix sytem, it is usually in

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Once you have installed the `@angular/cli` package globally, you will be able to do `ng update`.

Note that you could also use

```
/your/project/base/path/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng upgrade
```

without having to install the `@angular/cli` package globally, but if you are planning on using it often, installing it globally might be a better option.

Comment: thanks that worked as far. I have just another question. I have no updated with ng update to angular 8. Shouldn't the routing automatically adapt to the new lazy loading style? Because it didn't in my project

Comment: @ColinRagnarök depending on your project, you might have to edit it yourself. If you are unsure, you can always refer to the [angular upgrade guide](https://update.angular.io/)

Comment: I actually already looked it up, thats why I thought it would work automated. But it looks like I have to do it manually:/ I actually noticed that the app still runs when having the old lazy loading setup. Is it actually needed to update that or do I have any disadvantages?

Comment: Well, it might be deprecated in the next versions, i can't tell you exactly when but it might come soon.